# tab control webpart?

Tags: web-part, publishing-site

I am using SharePoint Server 2007 Enterprise with Windows Server 2008 Enterprise. I am developing using VSTS 2008 + C# + .Net 3.5 + ASP.Net.

I want to develop a WebPart, like a tab based control, like task manager, items (e.g. processes, users, etc.) are managed by tab on the top for different categories, and in each category tab, items are organized in list. I need to get information about which tab is selected in my requirement.

Any reference code or document?

Comment: @George2: What exactly are you asking here? How to retrieve the list data? We prefer specific questions here. It seems like you are asking for someone to give you a complete solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could delegate the tab stuff to a jQuery plugin (just google), all you then need to do is render the correct html.

e.g. you render div elements with a certain class and let the jQuery plugin transform this to tabs on the client.

Not sure what you mean by "I need to get information about which tab is selected in my requirement" and whether this requirement is still valid when you implement it as suggested.

Comment: "a jQuery plugin" -- I find some ones. Could you recommend me an easy to use one and easy to integrate with C# code (I need C# code to read list content from SharePoint List and display in different tabs) from your experience please?

Answer (score 0):

Christophe Humbert's [Easy Tabs](http://sp2010.pathtosharepoint.com/SharePoint-User-Toolkit/Pages/Easy-Tabs-v5.aspx) would be an ideal option to use.  You place list view web parts on your desired page, then add in the easy tabs script and it converts it to a tabbed interface.